# execute function on Database using doctrine and symfony

Tags: mysql, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I have function on the database named getDtails(id) using `CREATE FUNCTION` on mysql

I can call it from mysql using `SELECT getDetails(10)` which return aninteger.

i want to execute it from symfony 1.4 using doctrine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this :

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()
       ->fetchAssoc('SELECT getDetails(10)');
```

You can replace `fetchAssoc` with `fetchArray` or `fetchBoth` as required.

Documentation of the `Doctrine_Connection` class is [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/doctrine1/latest/Doctrine_Connection.html)

Comment: Documentation link asking user name and password. what to do ?